# TeamCity/Sonar: Fail build if some metric increases

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-scan

We're using TeamCity with the Sonar plugin. Is there a way to fail the TeamCity build if some metric (i.e. number of Blocker issues, amount of technical debt, etc.) increases within Sonar, or if it just fails the Quality Gate? I haven't found any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

For now, the options available for this are

1. the [Build Breaker Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) (assuming Team City is compatible with the way this plugin woks)
2. adding a script step in your job (again, assuming TC supports it) to poll SQ in a loop for the completion of analysis report processing, then to grab the QG status and conditionally fail the build.

**2018 EDIT**
There is now non-blocking support for this within Jenkins Pipelines. More [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline).

Comment: The [Sonar Build Breaker Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) is supported by TeamCity.

Comment: I did try to use the Build Breaker plugin, but can't get it to show up within Sonar. I downloaded the jar and put it in the plugins dir, but when I log into Sonar, there is no evidence that it actually loaded the plugin, and when I check the startup logs, it makes no mention of loading it when it loads the other plugins. Is there some other step that I have to take? Based on what I've seen, this should be all I have to do to install the plugin.

Comment: Uhm... You dropped the plugin in, restarted, and there's _nothing_ in the startup log about this plugin?

Comment: Any update on this question? I am also struggling with the same issue. The build is not failing when the quality gate fails :(

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it using powershell scripts .Call the sonar rest api for the project using metric and metric key .Compare the result with the project if the metric value dose not match the exit from the build.